Puppeteer ignoring background-color property in generated PDF
I'm using Puppeteer to generate PDF reports from HTML content, and I'm encountering an issue where the background-color property defined in the HTML is being ignored in the generated PDF. I have ensured that the HTML content includes inline styles with background-color properties, but the background colors are not being applied in the PDF output.
Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using:
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function generatePDF() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  
  const htmlContent = `
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>PDF Report</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div style="background-color: red; padding: 20px;">
          <h1>Sample Report</h1>
          <p>This is a sample PDF report with a red background.</p>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  `;
  
  await page.setContent(htmlContent);
  const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({ format: 'A4' });
  
  await browser.close();
  
  return pdfBuffer;
}

generatePDF().then(pdfBuffer => {
  // Handle PDF buffer
});

In the above code, I'm setting the background-color property to red for a  element in the HTML content. However, when I generate the PDF using Puppeteer, the background color is not applied in the output PDF.
I have verified that the HTML content is correctly formatted and that other styles (e.g., padding) are applied as expected. I'm wondering if there's a limitation or issue with Puppeteer's rendering engine that is causing it to ignore the background-color property specifically.
How can I ensure that the background-color property defined in the HTML is properly applied in the generated PDF output using Puppeteer?

Unable to reproduce. I see the background running this code on Puppeteer 22.6.0 on Ubuntu 22.04. What OS/Pupp version are you using? Related: Puppeteer not rendering color, background color when I try to save PDF on disk and #2182.

The browser has default behavior of not printing backgrounds. Indeed from the docs there is special treatment to handle the colors:

To generate a PDF with the screen media type, call
page.emulateMediaType('screen') before calling page.pdf().
By default, page.pdf() generates a pdf with modified colors for
printing. Use the -webkit-print-color-adjust property to force
rendering of exact colors.

The second one means to add rule print-color-adjust: exact; to the relevant CSS. But maybe this step is not necessary.
await page.emulateMediaType('screen');
const pdfBuffer = await page.pdf({ format: 'A4' });

